# Difference between two dates in exact number of hours in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to calculate the exact hours difference between two datetime variables. The hours difference should be exact like this:

```
1.5
2
6.25
```

Anybody please help out..Thanks in advance...

Comment: 6.25 = How many hours and minutes?

Comment: @techdo surely you can work out houy many minutes there are in .25 of an hour?

Answer (score 33):

You could use [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx) to find the difference in minutes and convert that into hours:

```
select datediff(mi, startdate, enddate)
```

Assuming 1.5 means 1 hour and 30 minutes you could simply divide the result by 60:

```
select datediff(mi, startdate, enddate) / 60.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep it simple:

```
declare @date1 datetime
declare @date2 datetime

select @date1 = GETDATE();
select @date2 = '2013-02-02 14:05'

select DATEDIFF(hh, @date2, @date1)


Results
-----------
71

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF` returns an integer. Therefore it will never give the fractional part, as in the minutes.

Answer (score 4):

it will help you....

```
  Declare @Date1 dateTime
  Declare @Date2 dateTime 
  Set @Date1 = '22:30:00'   
  Set @Date2 = '00:00:00'
  Select Cast((@Date1 - @Date2) as Float) * 24.0
```

Comment: Brilliant. This solution is the ONLY one (so far) that over-comes the "DATEDIFF returns an INT which often over-flows" issue.

Comment: Except that it is using `FLOAT` which has it's own caveats and definitely not fulfil the requirement of 'exactly'.

Answer (score 3):

To get Exact Time Difference in HH:MM   try the below code in MS-SQL

```
 Declare @InTime datetime='2017-11-27 10:00:00',
 @OutTime datetime='2017-11-27 11:15:00'

 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,@InTime,@OutTime),0), 114)
 -----------
 Result
 01:15
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
declare @dt1 datetime, @dt2 datetime, @Seconds int
select @dt1='2013-02-05 14:05:55.113', @dt2 =getdate()
set @Seconds=datediff(second, @dt1, @dt2)

    declare @Hour nvarchar(50)
    declare @Min nvarchar(50)
    declare @MinTemp int        
    if @Seconds >0 
    begin
    set @Hour=cast((@Seconds / 3600) as nvarchar(20)) +' Hrs '
    set @MinTemp= (@Seconds % 3600) / 60
    set @Min=cast(@MinTemp as nvarchar(20))
    if  @MinTemp<10 
        select @Hour+'0'+@Min +' Min'
    else
        select @Hour+@Min +' Min'
    end
    else 
    select '00 Hrs 00 Min'
```