# First TimeIn Last TimeOut for each employee for respective days

Tags: sql-server

I have following table from which I want to extract the time calculated. I am looking to get the Hours Spent by each employee for each day.

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance 
(
     , EmpID INT
     , TimeIn datetime
     , TimeOut datetime
)
```

The sample record against this table I have is listed below.

```
 EmpID | AttendanceTimeIN  |  AttendanceTimeOut
 1       2017-04-01 9:00:00   2017-04-01 10:20:00
 2       2017-04-01 9:00:00   2017-04-01 12:30:00 
 1       2017-04-01 10:25:00  2017-04-01 17:30:00 
 2       2017-04-01 13:26:00  2017-04-01 14:50:00 
 2       2017-04-01 15:00:00  2017-04-01 18:00:00 
 1       2017-04-02 9:00:00   2017-04-02 11:00:00 
 1       2017-04-02 11:10:00  2017-04-02 12:00:00 
 2       2017-04-02 9:00:00   2017-04-02 12:00:00 
 1       2017-04-02 12:50:00  2017-04-02 18:00:00 
 2       2017-04-02 12:51:00  2017-04-02 18:00:00
```

I want to get the First TimeIn and Last TimeOut of and employee for each day to calculate how many hours a specific employee have spent in office each day. 
I'm bit confused that how to use Min/Max function so I can get both employees hours for each day.
The result set I am looking for should look like this.

```
 EmpID | AttendanceTimeIN  |  AttendanceTimeOut
 1       2017-04-01 9:00:00   2017-04-01 17:30:00
 2       2017-04-01 9:00:00   2017-04-01 18:00:00 
 1       2017-04-02 9:00:00   2017-04-02 18:00:00 
 2       2017-04-02 9:00:00   2017-04-02 18:00:00
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? You also state that your table `Attendance` has the columns with `TimeIn` and `TimeOut`, which are the data type `time`, however, your sample data clearly appears to be the datatype `datetime2(0)`. This makes a big difference, as if they are only `time` then how do we tell what day the data is for?

Comment: If the columns are infact DateTime, then This might help if you are looking for difference between 2 dates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705075/difference-between-two-dates-in-exact-number-of-hours-in-sql

Comment: Hi @Larnu I have tried this query 
SELECT EmpID, Min(TimeIn), Max(TimeOut), (Min(TimeIn)-Max(TimeOut)) AS [HoursSpent]
FROM Attendance

And I apologize for the time format actually I wrote the command here and copied the date from table so might have changed.
The result I got was 


`EmpID | AttendanceTimeIN  |  AttendanceTimeOut
 1       2017-04-01 9:00:00   2017-04-01 18:00:00
 2       2017-04-01 9:00:00   2017-04-01 18:00:00`

Comment: And No @SQLAndOtherStuffGuy your proposed solution didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TimeIn and TimeOut are datetime type (which they should be!), this solution works with the tests I did:

```
SELECT
    EmpID
    , MIN(TimeIn)
    , MAX(TimeOut)
FROM Attendance
GROUP BY EmpID, CAST(TimeIn AS DATE)
```

the `GROUP BY` clause means that there's one row for each employee and each day, since `CAST`ing to `DATE` gets rid of the time part. `MIN` and `MAX` then just inherently work.

Comment: Oh my gosh this worked. You have no idea how much relief you have given me. This was stuck in my head for 2 days.
Thank you Kristian <3